# What's the difference between Stackechange blender and blender artistes

Tags: discussion

What are the differences between them and in which way should we use each?

Comment: The two are totally different, Stack Exchange are question and answer sites with strict rules, while Blender Artists is a casual forum

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack exchange is a question and answers site, not a forum. It is meant to be used for focused questions that require a concrete answer (more on this on the [help] section, or on the [tour]). It is not a place for discussions, opinions or showcase your work.

Blenderartists.org is a forum with many specialized sub-forums, there you can ask questions as well, and discuss your opinions and voice out your grievances. Note that threads on that site can go on an on, so finding concrete information it is not as simple and straightforward as on this site. Blenderartists.org has more traffic and participants. But the signal-to-noise ratio can be harder to navigate.

So if you just want a simple answer, use the stackechange site. For mixed topics and random conversations use the other one.